# Find character in one or more of several positions via regex

Tags: regex

I've been "cheating" at the new [Wordle](https://www.powerlanguage.co.uk/wordle/) game and using it to develop my regex skills. I'm working with a list of 5 character English words and writing regex to find possible answers to the game. I've encountered a regex expression that I don't know how to write. Wordle will tell you that a character is in the word, but that it is not in a certain position. That implies that this character will appear in one or more of the other four positions.

So, if I learn that the word does not have an 'n' in the fifth position, I can exclude that by writing:

`^....[^n]$`

But I actually have more information than that. In addition to an 'n' not being in the fifth position, I also know that one or more 'n' chars will be in the first four characters. I can't figure out how to specify that any character is acceptable for three of the four first positions and that an 'n' is acceptable in one more of those positions, but must appear in at least one position.

How can I specify that with a regex?

Comment: @CarySwoveland - check out both answers below - they both do what I want..

Comment: @CarySwoveland - I'm searching an english language word list for matches to an unknown word, where I have certain information about what the word is. So I know the word does not have an 'n' in the last position, and I know that an 'n' appears one more more times in the first four positions. I'm trying to find, in that word list, all the words that might match what I know about the word I'm searching for. You should try the Wordle game linked in the question to understand why I'm asking..

Comment: I admit it. I am an idiot. This morning your question is clear to me, why it was not before I cannot say. Another way: `^(?=.{5}$).*n.*[^n]$`, which, if the regex need not confirm the word has five characters can be simplified to `n.*[^n]$`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming Lookaheads are supported, you may use the following pattern:

```
^(?=.*n).{4}[^n]$
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0xTEdd/1)**.

**Breakdown:**

- `^` - Beginning of the string.
- `(?=.*n)` - Assert that the current position is followed by zero or more characters, then an 'n'.
- `.{4}` - Match any four characters.
- `[^n]` - Match any character except for 'n'.
- `$` - End of string.

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks - look aheads are a subject I have delved into every once in awhile and then promptly forget all about them. Great answer - thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use an alternation `|` in a group matching an `n` char on 1 of the 4 positions:

```
^(?:...n|..n.|.n..|n...)[^n]$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1pCWs9/1)

Comment: Thanks for this answer also. I mildly prefer the lookahead answer, but yours is clever too, and I upvoted it!